# Inserting CSP sites through apex code

Tags: apex, csp

I have a use case where I want to insert CSP site through apex, Is it possible or there is no way we can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex DML is not supported for object `CspTrustedSite`. You will get a `DML operation Insert not allowed on CspTrustedSite`.

But your Apex can do an REST HttpCallout to create the `CspTrustedSite`

- Endpoint: `/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/CspTrustedSite`
- Method: `POST`
- Body: See [CspTrustedSite SObjectReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_csptrustedsite.htm)

  ```
  Http h = new Http();
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setEndpoint(urlToYourSFDCInstance);  // you could use Named Credentials here too
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setBody(JSON.serialize(new CspTrustedSite(DeveloperName = 'xxx', ...));
  HttpResponse resp = h.send(req);
  ```

[Http doc reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve all the existing Csp's?

Comment: sure - use the REST API query (or possibly APEX SOQL) .Note your question was downvoted because it did not demonstrate any research